# Is it possible to install Apache superset on a ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, apache-superset

I am working on Apache Superset, I was able to install it on a linux EC2 instance using docker , is there is any possibility to install it on ECS ?

Comment: I don't see any reason it wouldn't work on ECS. Are you running into a specific issue trying to deploy it to ECS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to this.

First you can take the container image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset) and build an ECS task def / ECS service around it by bringing it up standalone. Make sure you enable [ECS exec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html) to be able to execute into the container and launch those commands. I have not tested this but I see no reason why it should not work.

I have also spent some time trying to make the docker compose files in the Superset GH repo work with Amazon ECS. You can read more about my findings [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/14965).